# Pre-populating a column value upon list creation

Tags: custom-list

We are trying to implement a small workshop registration system on our SharePoint.

Workshops are offered in different cities and at different times a year. For each event we have a list where people can sign up. However, I need the date and location information to be pre-populated as soon as a new item is created (or on the new item form, whichever is easier).

I thought about creating a separate "master" list with each workshop information, but I'm unsure on how to relate these two lists. I would still need an ID of some sort to relate to the correct workshop on each registration list

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't Default Value  on column list meet your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - so after researching the issue decided for a solution that is less automated. The workshop facilitator would have to first register the class information in the master list, where a field classID would be manually populated. Then the facilitator would create a new list with the exact name of that classID.

Unfortunately, since lists don't know their own name, had to add javascript on a HTML Form Web Part to pull the current url from the address bar and strip down to the list name. Then this value is passed to the textbox (have to have it and make sure it has both and 'id' and a 'name' or SharePoint won't allow connections) then pushed onto a hidden field in the InfoPath form where user's sign up. However, there's still [an issue for which another question has been posted](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175335/javascript-to-submit-web-part-without-click).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might be on the right track with the "master list" option if I understand what you are trying to do correctly.

It sounds like you want to define a list of workshop sessions, and have users be able to register for a session of their choice in a separate registrations list.

If that is the case, would a lookup column on your registrations list that 'looks up' the sessions on your workshops list do the trick?

That way when a user creates an item in the registrations list, they can select which session to attend.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that is close to what we're trying to do. However, we have a link from our website to the specific list the user needs to register for each session. How can we pre-select the correct value from the drop-down?

Comment: Maybe you could pass a query string parameter in the link, and then use some javascript on the form page to read the query string and select the drop down value that way?