# Javascript to submit Web Part without click

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, web-part, infopath, connection

[From a previous question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173057/pre-populating-a-column-value-upon-list-creation), I am able to populate a textbox with a value I can use to reference another list. However, in order for this functionality to be as user friendly as possible, I would like for this value to get submitted to the connected InfoPath Form Web Part without requiring the user to click on a submit button.

[image]

I've looked at the code that is used with the standard web part:

```
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/></div>
```

Is there a way to call the *SFSubmit* function from the window.onload event handler in Javascript?

Edit - ok, maybe not on window.onload... that seems to create a never-ending loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

It's been a few months but forgot to post the solution for my problem. In consulting with a Microsoft resource, we resorted to using a hidden column and setting it's default value to the name of the list. This value can be used to reference the master schedule list by the classID field

However, we recently migrated to SP2013 and now I can't seem to reference an external list (to the current one) in the workflow... looks like our IT might have broken this functionality on accident or so I hope